# Does an openpyxl workbook knowns its own filename?

Tags: python, openpyxl

In Excel, a workbook knows whether it already was given a filename or not. This changes Excel behavior when one clics on the save button. If the wb has no name, the save button redirects to the "save as" action. I wonder if openpyxl has a similar mechanism. This would help me in a function such as:

```
def smartSaveXLbook(wb, defaultName='MyBook.xlsx'):
    if wb.properties.title:  # this does not work. No wb passes this test :-(
        print("wb has a name :", wb.properties.title) # wb.properties.title always empty
        wb.save() # wants to save with the current existing name
    else:
        wb.save(defaultName) # Simplified version here. I will grant name uniqueness.
```

Answer (score 3):

No, and for good reason: once openpyxl has read the file, it releases it and any other application can do what they want with it. But you can easily write a wrapper function that would store the name used to open the workbook. You could then use parameters to work with this: overwrite or always new?

Comment: Thanks! Not only the answer but a very neat explanation.